# A nicer way to create an ad hoc iterator than "vec![a,b,c].into_iter()"?

Tags: rust, iterator

The expression `vec![a, b, c].into_iter()` seems unnecessarily long.Is there something better?

The doc for itertools [kmerge](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.kmerge) gives this example:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let a = (0..6).step(3);
let b = (1..6).step(3);
let c = (2..6).step(3);
let it = vec![a, b, c].into_iter().kmerge();
itertools::assert_equal(it, vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

When you just want to create an ad hoc iterator of values, is there anything better?
Maybe something like `iter![a,b,c]` (if `iter` is taken, then some other word).
If this is possible, I've got to believe that someone's already done it, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Note that if you were writing a `for` loop, the `.into_iter()` call would be implicit, so you could omit that (and drop `vec!` since it could just be a simple array). It's just when you need to explicitly convert to an iterator that it gets a little more verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array works just as well as a `Vec` and avoids the heap allocation.

```
[a, b, c].into_iter()
```

Perhaps the documentation predates Rust 1.53 when this was [stabilized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%5BT%3B%20N%5D).

Comment: The example code is definitely on the older side; `Itertools`'s `.step` has been deprecated for over four years, in favor of the `std::iter`-provided `.step_by`, so the example would predate Dec, 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! Putting it all together, we can make `[a, b, c].kmerge()` work:

```
    use itertools::Itertools;

    let a = (0..6).step_by(3);
    let b = (1..6).step_by(3);
    let c = (2..6).step_by(3);
    let it = [a, b, c].kmerge();
    itertools::assert_equal(it, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

The extra step is to extend all IntoIterator's:

```
use itertools::kmerge;
use itertools::KMerge;

impl<I: IntoIterator> IntoItertoolsPlus for I {}
pub trait IntoItertoolsPlus: IntoIterator {
    fn kmerge(self) -> KMerge<<Self::Item as IntoIterator>::IntoIter>
    where
        Self: IntoIterator + Sized,
        Self::Item: IntoIterator,
        <<Self as IntoIterator>::Item as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialOrd,
    {
        kmerge(self)
    }
}
```

I'm going to use this method for two of my own functions. They both accept a variable number of same-type inputs.